# Where to implement session manager in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to implement session manager in android, where should i implement it in main activity or extend application class, do explain which is better and why

Comment: What session you mean?Try to elaborate the question?Login credential of the user?

Comment: i am storing acess token in shared prefences. The session manager class checks if the token is not null

Comment: are you doing social login ?

Comment: Did you got a fix?

Comment: Try this one http://simpleandroidfeast.blogspot.in/2017/03/shared-preference-in-android.html

Comment: https://medium.com/@rishabh115/making-a-simple-session-manager-using-snappydb-73675cb74f4

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a splash activity for checking the session would be better so from that you could redirect to a main activity with logged in or logged out user

you can write shared preference in an activity or in a application.Either ways it works the same. I prefer using that in an activity or in a singleTon.

**Setting values in Preference:**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("ABC", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("username", "Gibin");
 editor.putInt("access_token", "qwertyuiop");
 editor.commit();
```

**Retrieve data from preference:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("ABC", MODE_PRIVATE); 
id = prefs.getString("access_token", "");
if (id.equals("")) {
//  session is available
}else
//session is not available
```